# Apply an alternative layout on frontend created articles

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

I created a Create Article menu Item Type and need to apply an alternative layout to all article created using this frontend form. But Joomla not provide this option. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is not clear,please provide more information, what you actually want.

Comment: @Toretto I have a section in my site called About me, where all registered author can add an article. So I create a Create Article menu Item Type for that purpose. The problem is that this article uses an alternate layout. And I need to apply this layout to all articles created by authors.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a business decision what fields to allow or not allow to be modified from the front end but in general the thinking is that too many complex choices in the front end is not a great idea, but for your business logic that may make complete sense.  Take a look at how the display of image and links fields in the front end are turned on and off.   You could override the edit layout and bring some more fields forward probably.

Comment: Please, see my comment above.

Comment: Just make that the default value of the alternatve layout  field for your override.

Comment: Like I said just do it like any other JForm,  if it is a hard coded thing that's always the same just use a plugin that only applies in that category. Read the docs on making a plugin.